# How to determine if an event raised 

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Can you tell me how to determine which events are raised in winform
or how to add all raised events to a list or to a file in c#?

Comment: Are you just wanting to debug events or are you wanting to log events to a file when the running application is production quality? What is the specific application for your question?

Comment: i want to log every event in application and to do this without subscribing to every event in the program.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like you want to see each event that is fired.  To do that, you would need to subscribe to every event.  If you really want to go down that road, you could create one method that would read the passed-in variables and tell you what event called the method.  Then you could hook that method up to every event in your winform app.  The list would be enormous, but it would give you an idea of when each event was fired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Managed Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx). It displays a list of processes in a treeview in the left side of the window and a PropertyGrid on the right side. You can expand the process to see top-level windows in that process.

When you select a control, the PropertyGrid shows properties on that control. Clicking on the Events tab will display events such as MouseMove on the currently selected control in the treeview. To begin logging events, click the Start Logging button. The output will appear as shown.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I understand your question correctly, but I am still going to try and answer it:
When you subscribe to an event, your method will be called when that event is raised. In your method, you can log that the event was raised.

Comment: i dont want to subscribe to all messages, i want get all the raised events

Comment: @namco - What do you mean by "get all the raised events"?  Do you mean you want your app to be notified whenever an event is raised?

Comment: @namco: That is what my answer is doing. I reworded a small part of my answer, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @namco, you really need to be more specific in your question. Nobody knows what you're needing and in order to properly answer your question we need to know what you're trying to do. The solution is trivial but we need information from you.

Comment: OK, think that we have a form and we have some components(for ex. Button, CheckBox, etc). When i click on the button program must add to list box "Button1_CLick event has raised", when i click on the form it must add "form1_Click event has raised" and so on.

Comment: As I and others said: You can only know this, if you subscribed to that event. There is no other way to do this.

Comment: @namco Can it be an external tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about windows events, you need to override the **WndProc()** method.

[**Control.WndProc Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx)

[**WndProc API basics**](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/wndproc.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the events that are declared or inherited by the current Type

```
 typeof(MyClass).GetEvents()
```

After that for each you can add a simple delegate

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
foreach (var e in typeof(MyClass).GetEvents())
{
   FieldInfo fi = typeof(MyClass).GetField(e.Name, 
                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
   object value = fi.GetValue(instance);
   if (value == null)
   {
       e.AddEventHandler(instance, handler);
   }
}
```